# Change DropdownButtonFormField value programmatically

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to change the DropdownButtonFormField value on event (button press for example) using setState. But it's not working.

Note: it works in case I use DropdownButton, but with DropdownButtonFormField it's not responding.

Here is a simple code showing what I'm trying to implement.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Testing(),
    );
  }
}

class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestingState createState() => _TestingState();
}

class _TestingState extends State<Testing> {
  String selectedValue;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          DropdownButtonFormField(
            value: selectedValue,
            items: ['one', 'two'].map((value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedValue = value;
              }); 
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('test'),
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                selectedValue = 'two';
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Define instance variable from Global Key and pass it to **DropdownButtonFormField**

```
final dropdownState = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
```

You can change the value of dropDownFieldItem by calling this method

```
dropdownState.currentState.didChange('two');
```

final code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Testing(),
    );
  }
}

class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestingState createState() => _TestingState();
}

class _TestingState extends State<Testing> {
  String selectedValue;
  final dropdownState = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          DropdownButtonFormField(
            key: dropdownState,
            value: selectedValue,
            items: ['one', 'two'].map((value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedValue = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('test'),
            onPressed: () {
              dropdownState.currentState.didChange('one');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here working normally with `DropdownButtonFormField` and `DropdownButton`.

flutter --version

```
Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.9 • channel stable •
```

Comment: I upgraded flutter, and tested,It works on stable channel. But in beta it's not working. I'm using flutter web that's why I work on beta channel.. but really appreciated answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter version 1.17.2 that bug was fixed, so be sure to upgrade.

Github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56898

Fixed in version 1.17.2: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel#1172-may-28-2020